# A deceptively simple eight piece endgame

Tags: analysis, endgame, rook-endgame

I am in the dark about the following endgame, with white to move. May someone with FinalGen (or a powerful engine) give me a response? Is it a White win or a draw?

```
[FEN "8/1k6/5R2/P7/1KP4p/5P2/8/5r2 w - - 0 1"]
```

Comment: Not sure this is such a useful question on a question/answer site like this. Why not just check yourself with Finalgen?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have this instrument

Comment: For what its worth, my Rybka checks, and then trades pawns, calling it 2.78 at about 33 depth.. which is pretty winnish, right?  I dunno.  I can't remember but I think I don't have the endgame tablebases installed, and I bet it would just know immediately if I did.

Comment: I guess I should specify, Rybka checks with Bc6... here:  1. Rb6+ Ka7 2. Rh6 Rxf3 3. Rxh4 Rf1 4. c5 Kb7 5. Kb5 Rb1+ 6. Rb4 Rg1 7. a6+ Ka7  ... still calling it 2.78 pawns ahead, at 34 depth

Comment: I think White has no better than trade f against h immediately (otherwise, Black gets the P for nothing, also a draw by Syzygy), and the resulting endgame a+c is *usually* draw. Thus it is easy to assign Justin's variant even with Nalimov: 3...Rf1? loses, only draw 3...Kb7.

Comment: @JustinStafford I'd strongly recommend using an engine that's not as outdated as Rybka. :D Stockfish is free and by now more than 400 rating points stronger than Rybka. As for Finalgen, oh I see now that the Finalgen site is down. A quick search gave me this suggestion https://www.freesoft.org/software/hoffman/ although I have not tried this software so I can't tell if it is any good. I could also upload my local installation of Finalgen I suppose.

Comment: An engine evaluation of +2.xx at depth 30+ in an 8-men endgame like that is **not** as winnish as it would be in the middlegame - essentially it reads: while White retains their 2 extra pawns plus 0.78 of positional advantage during the next 30+ plies, they won't be able to make any decisive progress (else the score would go through the roof). Maybe the engine will find a way deeper in the tree, but it's not unlikely that it won't (at least there is no straightforward one).

Answer (score 2):

Stockfish 14+ NNUE evaluates this position as +0.5 (depth = 62, 22036k nodes/s).

The principal variation (see below) leads to a **theoretical draw** according to the 7-piece tablebases.

```
[FEN "8/1k6/5R2/P7/1KP4p/5P2/8/5r2 w - - 0 1"]

1. Rf7+ Ka6 2. Rh7 Rxf3 {Theoretical Draw according to the 7-piece tablebases} (2. Rf6+ Kb7 3. f4 h3 4. Rb6+ Kc7 5. Rh6 Rxf4 {Theoretical Draw according to the 7-piece tablebases})
```

Other lines suggested:
From [Justin Stafford](https://chess.stackexchange.com/users/26234/justin-stafford)'s [comment](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/33815/a-deceptively-simple-eight-piece-endgame/37484#comment53245_33815): 1. Rb6+ Ka7 2. Rh6 Rxf3 3. Rxh4 (**theoretical draw**)
From [David](https://chess.stackexchange.com/users/18809/david)'s [answer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/33820/26335): 1. Rh6 Rxf3 (**theoretical draw**)

Answer (score -4):

No need for engine analysis, that's a win for White since that parciular a+c pawn endgame is won. White can simply trade the other two pawns with Rh6

Comment: That's not true, Rh6 Rxf3 Rxh4 is a well known theoretical draw. Black defends this kind of position by putting the king on the short side (i.e. a file in this case) and then checks with the rook whenever the white king steps out from the c pawns cover.

Comment: @koedem Although the position after that line is a draw, Black must play exact. If Black took your advice literally and played Ka6, Ka7, or Ka8 the next move, White would have a forced win, according to the lichess tablebase.

Comment: @DM yes, this was not a suggestion for specific moves, it is the general idea of how to hold this endgame. It is in fact quite difficult to defend / easy to screw up as a human.

Comment: OP has asked for theoretical status.  1. Rh6 Rxf3 is indeed a theoretical draw by the 7 piece tablebases.  However, I also appreciate the practical considerations of playability, though the answer could be improved with more discussion for these considerations.